# Adjust streaming rate in dataflow pubsub to bigquery template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to use the Google-provided template for streaming data from Pubsub to Bigquery, although I want the streaming to be done at 1 row per second. How can I update the streaming speed? Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: is there any reason why?

Comment: Because I am using Data Studio to visualize the real-time streaming data and it would look good if the data came in every second..

Comment: oh - note that Data Studio doesn't refresh in real time - hence you won't be able to see data refreshing every second regardless

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with the template. Only option I see is throttling the rate of messages published to the topic.

Comment: Any way I can do that? I am using cloud dataflow google-template job to publish data to pubsub topic from json files stored in google cloud storage..

Comment: @ParthDesai, please open a new question for Pub/Sub message throttling.